# Change the name and id on a form input in rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, form-for

I'm trying to add a wysiwyg editor. To get it to work on the input field you need the html to be similar to this

```
<textarea id="edit" name="content"></textarea>
```

Problem is cant get it to show a textarea to look like this

here is my coding

```
 <%= f.label :template, "Template" %>
 <%= f.text_area :template, :input_html => { :id => 'edit', :name => 'content' } %>
```

and here is what it produces

```
<textarea input_html="{:id=&gt;&quot;edit&quot;, :name=&gt;&quot;content&quot;}" name="category[template]" id="category_template">
```

Comment: Please see: http://apidock.com/rails/v4.2.1/ActionView/Helpers/FormHelper/text_area

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
<%= f.label :template, "Template", for: 'edit' %>    
<%= f.text_area :template, { :id => 'edit' } %>
```

will set the id  - you probably don't want to be changing the name of the field if you want it submitted to the :template attribute in your model.